# Change TextBlock Text from itemcount via xaml

Tags: wpf

I have an `Expander` that will contains a list of elements, this is the structure:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="#4F4F4F">
  <Expander.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="22">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Orange" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
      <TextBlock Text=" match" FontSize="22" Foreground="White" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Expander.Header>
  <ItemsPresenter />
</Expander>
```

What I want achieve is that when ItemCount of the second TextBlock is `> 1` the text of the last TextBlock `match` will change automatically in `matches` is this possible via xaml? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the TextBlock Text in Style

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="22">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Orange" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    <TextBlock FontSize="22" Foreground="White" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value=" matches" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemCount}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value=" match" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Wow very interesting solution, thank you very much for this :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

It's less meaningful to do this in pure Xaml.

You can write a converter for this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource ItemCountConverter}}" />

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value > 1 ? "matches" : "match";
    }
```